# Display an image located in the database in Django

Tags: python, html, database, django, image

I just want to display an image that i have uploaded through the admin module, through an html image tag on a web page.
The image is located in /home/user/work/djcode/media/chicks/blondie.jpg.

Here is the relevant part of my models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    model_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='chicks/')
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.model_name
```

Here is is the relevant part of my views.py

```
def main(request):
    i = get_object_or_404(Image, pk=1)
    return render_to_response('polls/main.html', {'image': i}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The html tag that i am using is simply

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_ROOT }}/{{ image.model_pic.url }}">
```

From settings.py, my media root is MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/user/work/djcode/media'

Note that the variable {{ image.model_pic.url }} shows "chicks/blondie.jpg" through the html template so I think that my image object is indeed well sent to the template.

Anyone could give me a hand with that ? That would be really helpful.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 15):

Your use of the url function on the image field in your template is not quite correct - `{{ image.model_pic.url }}` should fix the issue. You just need to drop the `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` bit.

Your html should be -

```
<img src="{{ image.model_pic.url }}">
```

Have a look at the documentation on [using files in models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/files/#using-files-in-models).

If you're still having trouble then it may be an issue with [serving static files.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/) Serving static files in django varies depending on whether you're doing it in production or just using the `python manage.py runserver` command.

To server media files during development (with python manage.py runserver), make sure you've got your MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT correct in your settings.py then you can append the following to your url conf -

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Have a look at the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/) for instructions on how to serve files in production.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `{{MEDIA_URL}}` or `{{STATIC_URL}}` , the choice depends on how you manage your files on server. if you use `{{STATIC_URL}}` this is best.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the following:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
            .....
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```