# Django: Using a for loop to view all images from my db - using img src

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am currently learning Django and making my first steps. I try to build a webgallery to learn all the basic stuff. I successfully displayed some images using static files. So I tried saving Images through ImageFields and "upload_to" in my DB, saving it to my static directory. I tried to display everyone of them with a for loop in an  tag. My img displays properly with using a {% static %} tag but when I try to insert a {{ }} Tag it isn't working, although it's the same url it doesn't work.

- I tried changing my STATIC FILE in settings.py
- I tried various other forms of nesting my  {{}} in there
- Reading the docs to staticfile https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/
- This thread [Display an image located in the database in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675738/display-an-image-located-in-the-database-in-django)
- This thread https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/files/#using-files-in-models

My Code:

```
<p>Overview</p>

{% block content %}

<div>
{% for image in images %}

  {{ image.img_photo }} <!-- webgalleries/test.jpg -->

  {% load static %}
  <img src="{% static 'webgalleries/test.jpg' %}" alt="{{ image }}"> <!-- working -->
  <img src="{% static '{{ image.img_photo }}' %}" alt="{{ image }}"> <!-- not working -->

{% empty %}
  <p>No content</p>

{% endfor %}

</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

I expect the output to be an img from my static directory.

A hint, some advice or other forms of help is highly appreciated.

Thank you so much!

Comment: you must give `.url` after the image object, like this `<img src="{% static '{{ image.img_photo.url }}' %}" alt="{{ image }}">`

Comment: @SammyJ I tried that already. I tried it with .url and .path, both are not working

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean give like this, `<img src="{{ image.img_photo.url }}" alt="{{ image }}">`

Answer (score 1):

okay if you want to display images from database you should do these steps :

1- go to your settings.py and write this code there ,

```
MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"media")
MEDIA_URL= "/media/"
```

2- then create new folder in your project called 'media' and create folder inside 'media' called 'images' (finally result will be like this 'media/images' )

3- go to your model.py in your class that having 'img_photo'

and you should write the model like this

```
class Images(models.Model):

    img_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',null=True, blank=True)

    def get_image(self):
        if self.img_photo and hasattr(self.img_photo, 'url'):
            return self.img_photo.url
        else:
            return '/path/to/default/image'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.img_photo
```

4-  go to admin.py then write :

```
from yourapp.models import Images
```

then add this line below

admin.site.register(Images)

then open your terminal or console and write :

1- python manage.py makemigrations

2- python manage.py migrate

5- in html code you must write :

```
    {% for image in Images %}

    <img src="{{ image.get_image }}" >

    {% endfor %}
```

- go to admin panel and upload any photo for test

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your solution and it's still not working. How do you implement the url in an img, like this: <p><img src="{{ image.get_image }}"></p>? That's not working.

Comment: i'm sorry for this mistake you should write <img> not <p> ,, try this please in html file 


<img  src="{{ image.get_image }}" >

Comment: try again with new change in html and if it work please mark my answer

Comment: I tried that, but it's not working. That was my stated problem. I think it has something to do with my URL path. Did you tested your solution, is it working at yours?

Comment: yes it's work with me ,, i have edit the answer 

please edit the model as i written ( copy and paste  )

and in html edit the for as i written and it will work

Comment: wait , do you add the Images model to admin.py ??

go to admin.py then write :

1- from yourapp.models import Images
2- admin.site.register(Images)

then open your terminal or console and write 

1- python manage.py makemigrations
2- python manage.py migrate

after do that runserver and try upload new photo for test