# django media image url not showing up

Tags: django

I can't seem to figure out why my media images are not showing up in my template. I've read many articles but couldn't resolve. I have a model that has a relation with another model that has an imagefield

```
class Ad(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='ads', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.TextField(max_length=240)
    text_description = models.TextField(max_length=2500)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=False)
```

The imagefield from the `Company` model gets uploaded to a folder called /logos/ that is under /media/

```
class Company(models.Model):

    logo = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='logos/')
```

And these are the settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

and urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and views.py:

```
class SingleAd(DetailView):
    model = Ad
```

Then im trying to loop through images and add to the template:

```
{% load static %}
    {% for ad in object_list %}
    
        <div>
            {% if ad.company.logo %}
            <img src="{{ ad.company.logo.url }}" height="100"/>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

    {% endfor %}
```

The result is a blank image (although the concrete object has an image) and the HTML renders such a tag

```
<img src="/media/logos/security-265130_1920_IBWqpIq.jpg" height="100">
```

The image does exist and with the correct path and name as shown in rendered img tag. What am I doing wrong here? Staticfiles images like the website brand and background images are being rendered as expected

Comment: take look here maybe will help you .. also can you show me views.py code for image 
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58649144/12258785

Comment: Hi @KokHyvv I added views.py to original post. Basically its just a ListView

Comment: Did you check parent tag of image? Maybe parent tag have `display:none`.

Comment: @NguyễnVũThiên checked. Not the issue

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and problem was fixed